# message: "PostConfirmation invocation failed due to error AccessDeniedException."

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I was trying to code a user password reset function when
[an API error occured](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1Ge5.png):

```
{__type: "UnexpectedLambdaException",…}
message: "PostConfirmation invocation failed due to error AccessDeniedException."
__type: "UnexpectedLambdaException"
```

I'm using Angular 10 and Cognito to manage user

Here is the code I'm calling:

```
    async ConfirmResetPass(): Promise<void> {
    const Username = this.email;
    const code = this.resetPasswordForm.controls['confirmCode'].value;
    const password = this.resetPasswordForm.controls['password'].value;
    Auth.forgotPasswordSubmit(Username, code, password)
      .then((data: any) => {
        if (data) {
          this._router.navigate(['auth/sign-in']);
          this._notification.show(`SUCCESS!`);
        }
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        this._notification.show(`error: ${e.message}`);
      });}
```

And I tried removing all the functions in the Lambda but is still get errors

Does anybody know why I might be getting this error?

Comment: Looks like an error that comes from the backend or a third-party package..

Comment: Tuyen, do you have permission to allow Cognito execute lambda?

Comment: @MikeOne Package still run ok!

Comment: @NghiaDo I don't know! how can I find it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is for permission of lambda. Please check from your side

[image]